# How can i highlight a specific rows on UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, sdk, ios4

Hi i have UITableView with x rows and my cell data   loaded with plist file , i wanna implement a UITextField that user  inserts the cell number and then after done button the cell going to highlight and show the cell row , for example enter 104 and then show me the row 104 .
is there anyway ? thank you .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-[UITableView [selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)]

Comment: Daniel i have problem , i have UITextView and user insert number there : so i don't know why this code doesn't work : [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:@"%i",myTextView inSection:0 ]

Comment: The row parameter needs to be an integer, so you need to figure out which row myTextView is in, and pass that.